# Badges oversized and cut off on mobile site

Tags: bug, badges, design, mobile-web

I have no idea if it's just a local problem, but I don't remember changing any settings recently.

I am seeing a few bugs on the mobile version of the site, but the one I've seen consistently over the past few days is badges rendering too big for their container.

Here is an example screenshot:

[image: mobile site screenshot]

I'm using a nexus 5. I searched for similar bug reports here to no avail before posting this.

Can anyone confirm that it's reproducible?

Can anyone explain why it's happening?

Comment: Related: [Misalignment of badges/numbers on user-profile page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5839/5764)