# Badge icon partially cut off on the profile page under communities section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

Badge icons are partially cut off on the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) when hovering the reputations under **Communities (x)** section.

**Screenshot and GIF for reference:**

| Screenshot | GIF |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: GIF] |

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 89.0.2 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit) |
| Zoom | 100% |

Comment: I would call this "partially cut off", or, "clipped". Btw. I can't reproduce it in Firefox or in Chromium on Ubuntu (even while in Chromium these icons show up misaligned a bit).

Comment: @Levente Instead of "partially visible", "partially cut off" is proper wording, let me update in the post

Comment: yeah, yeah, we already [tackled this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364832/786798) :) Give SE 6 to 8 weeks to fix

Comment: Issue fixed (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367459/395497)). Thanks for the report!